# How to test a NoSQL database system

Tags: nosql, benchmarking

Recently,I am doing a test work about NoSQL database----"NoSQL database performance comparison ".But I am confused about what should be tested? In my plan I will test Redis,MongoDB,CouchDB and so on.
Can someone give me some advice?

Comment: Why do you want to use NoSQL?  The reasons will guide what you should be testing.  Note that there are very different models behind various databases, some of which trade e.g. durability for speed.  Your use case is important to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to test NoSQL databases by yourself because big NoSQL users like Google, Facebook, Twitter etc. already tested and use NoSQL.

But, if you still want to do something similar, then use `benchmark tools` which is provided by the NoSQL community.